# iOS PayPal SDK (Custom Field)

Tags: ios, paypal, payment

I want to know if there is a method with new iOS PayPal SDK to send a custom parameter to the PayPal , store it and when the transaction is completed the IPN send that parameter to my web-service .

1. I tried with MPL PayPal SDK but I want the direct credit card payment too (which is not supported by MPL)
2. I read about MECL SDK but it is deprecated
3. The new iOS PayPal SDK is perfect for me , but I don't have any idea how to send a custom parameter . Without this functionality , I cannot find a way to verify the transaction . I know Android SDK supports custom field and I find this very intriguing that iOS does not support this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the "custom" variable or pass-through variables are not supported in either mobile SDK at this time.

Comment: Hmm... I am pretty disappointed hearing this , because the android SDK support the "custom" variable. And more of this , I am more disappointed because for now , there is no method to use in order to check if the payment was done (i mean the real money transfer).

Comment: @ChirilaVasile can you let me know how to pass "custom" variable using Android. Is that MPL or Rest? Can you please share some details?

Comment: Both the iOS and Android mSDK's allow for the 'custom' variable as of a few versions ago.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about verifying the payment, [documentation to verify a payment is here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/).

iOS and Android are supposed to have feature parity. So, if you find a discrepancy, perhaps you could [open an issue](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues) that includes a link to the Android feature?